# Angular 6 Ngx typeahead options rendering

Tags: angular, angular6, typeahead

I am using [Angular ngx-bootstrap typeahead plugin](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead)

[image]

When I usign input typeahead in modal,

Option values show inside containner modal.

But I not want to show inside containner modal

**I want to show outside modal picture below.**

[image]

What do I need to set up?

Sorry for English.

Thank so much.

Comment: change the z-index of the type-head drop down ,also please post your code so that others can look at it

Comment: @JoelJoseph I set already, not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this method is good or not.

But

I can resolve already.

**Step** 1: Set `z-index` in Root `style.scss`

```
typeahead-container {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

**Step** 2: Add attribute `[container]="'body'"` inside Input typeshead tag

```
<input
   ....
   [container]="'body'"
   ....
   class="form-control">
```

**Result:**

[image]

Work for me.

Sorry for English.